# Multiple values in a rewrite rule, is it possible?

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm using url rewrites for a filter i'm building. The current solution works for one selected value. So if I select one type of dish like dinner, it goes to /recipes/dinner/.

But what if I want to filter on dinner and lunch? Is this possible, with the add_rewrite_rule?

The current solution is as followed.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'course';
    return $vars;
} );

add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%course%', '([^&]+)' );
}, 10, 0 );

add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^recipes/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=11&course=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}, 10, 0 );
```

And if it is possible what would be a logic url structure to follow?

Comment: What do you mean by _"…if I want to filter on dinner and lunch¿"_

Comment: The most filters use a get variable to filter on more taxonomies, something like ?course=dinner,lunch

But with url rewrite, you can't and don't want to use /recipes/dinner/lunch
What would be a good SEO approach? Something like /recipes/dinner-lunch/ or is it better to simple use a get variable?

Comment: Please use [edit]s to answer and clarify instead of comments. Thanks. And SEO topics are better asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand, you know are able to have an URL like `example.com/recipes/dinner/` or `example.com/recipes/lunch/` but now you also want to have an URL like `example.com/recipes/dinner-lunch/` that pulls posts from both "dinner" and "lunch" courses.

In currents state of WP rewrites this is not possible just with `add_rewrite_rule` but you also need to use `pre_get_posts` to edit the query based on value *catched* by the rewrite rule.

For example:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'course';
    return $vars;
} );

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^recipes/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=11&course=$matches[1]', 'top');
}, 10, 0);

add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
  if (! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('course')) {
     // explode the value of matched course by -
     $courses = explode('-', $query->get('course'));
     // update the value in query with an array
     $query->set('course', $courses);
  }
});
```

The issue here is that if a "course" has an hyphen in the name, the `explode` will break the query, so maybe you can use a less common separator.